# Appium creates driver very slowly. (Inspector loads elements tree very slowly.)

Tags: webdriver, appium-ios

### The problem

The app can be launched quickly when I use the Appium Desktop to create a session for inspector, but it takes too long to load the elements tree for inspector. This phenomenon happens only in some apps.

### Environment

- Appium version (or git revision) that exhibits the issue: Appium Desktop 1.6.1 (Appium Server 1.8.0)
- Last Appium version that did not exhibit the issue (if applicable):
- Desktop OS/version used to run Appium:MacOS 10.13.5
- Node.js version (unless using Appium.app|exe):10.1.0
- Mobile platform/version under test:iOS 10.3.3
- Real device or emulator/simulator:iPhone 7 real device
- Appium CLI or Appium.app|exe:

### Details

It's about 5 minutes to get a response loading the elements tree.

```
2018-06-28 09:40:05:339 - [debug] [XCUITest] Failed to create WDA session. Retrying...
2018-06-28 09:40:06:346 - [debug] [BaseDriver] Event 'wdaSessionAttempted' logged at 1530150006346 (09:40:06 GMT+0800 (CST))
2018-06-28 09:40:06:346 - [debug] [XCUITest] Sending createSession command to WDA
2018-06-28 09:40:06:347 - [debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [POST /session] to [POST http://localhost:8100/session] with body: {"desiredCapabilities":{"bundleId":"com    .chinaums.ttf6","arguments":[],"environment":{},"shouldWaitForQuiescence":true,"shouldUseTestManagerForVisibilityDetection":true,"maxTypingFrequency":60,"shouldUseS    ingletonTestManager":true}}
2018-06-28 09:45:28:282 - [debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Got response with status 200: {"value":{"sessionId":"9A6749D7-5A1D-431F-AA57-  E1126F189E95","capabilities":{"device":"iphone","browserName":null,"sdkVersion":"10.3.3","CFBundleIdentifier":null}},"sessionId":"9A6749D7-5A1D-431F-AA57-  E1126F189E95","status":0}
2018-06-28 09:45:28:282 - [debug] [BaseDriver] Event 'wdaSessionStarted' logged at 1530150328282 (09:45:28 GMT+0800 (CST))
2018-06-28 09:45:28:472 - [debug] [XCUITest] Cannot find a match for DerivedData folder path from lsof. Trying to access logs
2018-06-28 09:45:28:482 - [debug] [BaseDriver] Event 'wdaStarted' logged at 1530150328481 (09:45:28 GMT+0800 (CST))
2018-06-28 09:45:28:482 - [XCUITest] Skipping setting of the initial display orientation. Set the "orientation" capability to either "LANDSCAPE" or "PORTRAIT", if  this is an undesired behavior.
```

### Link to Appium logs

[appium_server_log](https://gist.github.com/waitshang/0aca7fbb410432bfa94131cb25df640d)

Answer (score 1):

I sloved it following this citation [Creating session takes over 5 minutes now with Xcode 9](https://discuss.appium.io/t/creating-session-takes-over-5-minutes-now-with-xcode-9/18971). 
Just add capability: waitForQuiescence = false